# MATE tries to automount floppy drive every login even if empty. How to make it stop?

Tags: 12.10, automount, mate, floppy

My PC has a 3.5" floppy drive and yes, I do use it. (Retrocomputing hobby.) I use Ubuntu 12.10 with MATE. At every login, the floppy drive lights up and I get the following message box:

[image: Floppy disk error message]

The title translates to: *It wasn't possible to mount Diskette Disk*

Fun fact: If I `rmmod floppy` and then `modprobe floppy` while logged in, the same message box appears again.

Also, if I eventually access a floppy disk, the motor won't stop spinning. If I do a `mdir` of it, after it returns, the motor stops, and then starts again. I suspect there's some process in MATE doing this. My `/etc/fstab` has nothing related to any removable media, just the root and swap partition.

How do I make MATE stop trying to access the floppy? I repeat, I don't want to disable the floppy. This behavior doesn't happen under CentOS 6 and GNOME 2.x.

Answer (score 2):

Can you uncheck this setting in mateconf-editor: /apps/caja/preferences/media_automount ? On my setup I could stop the SD card automounting after every logon or resume from standby.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure about the status in the various Ubuntu releases, but upstream mate-conf-editor is obsolete, and now dconf-editor (GUI) or gsettings (command line) are used.

In dconf-editor, the key is org/mate/desktop/media-handling/automount

From the command line:
gsettings set org.mate.media-handling automount false